# Как ускорить выполнение кода в консольном приложении?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Нужно придумать, как ускорить выполнение вот этого кода (консольное приложение).

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    
        string[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int n = Int32.Parse(line[0]); 
        int m = Int32.Parse(line[1]); 
        
        int [] cells = new int[n]; 

        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){  
            string[] line1 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int l = Int32.Parse(line1[0]); 
            int r = Int32.Parse(line1[1]);   
            int c = Int32.Parse(line1[2]);
            
            Array.Fill(cells, c, l-1, r-l+1);
        }

        Console.WriteLine( String.Join(" ", cells ));
    }
```

Это решение [вот этой задачи](https://algotester.com/uk/ArchiveProblem/DisplayWithEditor/40857#mySolutions). Может, как-то иначе можно было решить?

Вот перевод этой задачи:

> **Юный художник**
>
> *Ограничение: 1 сек., 256 МиБ*
>
> Юный художник Зеник имеет *n* последовательно расположенных белых
> ячеек, пронумерованных от 1 до *n* слева направо, которые можно
> окрашивать.
>
> Он выполняет *m*  покрасок такого вида: (*l,r,c*) — закрасить все
> ячейки от *l* до *r* включительно в цвет *c*. Каждая ячейка окрашена
> только в последний цвет, которым окрашивалась соответствующая ячейка.
>
> Вам нужно восстановить конечную картину, то есть определить цвет всех
> ячеек после выполнения всех запросов.
>
> **Входные данные** В первой строке задано два целых числа *n* и *m* — количество ячеек и количество окрасок.
>
> В следующих m строках задано по 3 целых числа *l*, *r* и *c*
>
> - соответствующая покраска.
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> В единственной строке выведите *n* целых чисел через пробел – цвета
> ячеек после всех окрасок. Считайте, что белый цвет – это 0.

Comment: А оно медленное? Как вы это поняли? Здесь конечно можно понапридумывать оптимизаций. Но не понимая, что это за код, что он должен делать и как именно он тестируется, здесь вряд-ли чего толкового получится. Даже версия .NET неизвестна. Отредактируйте вопрос, укажите больше деталей.

Comment: Я ребенку пытался помочь. Задача на автопроверке, нужно запустить. Пишет  - превышен лимит времени (1 секунда). Сделал все, что смог. 1.005 :)

Comment: Ну самое простое `.Split(' ')` заменить на `.Split()`, но не факт что поможет :) Но я не понимаю, что это за код, какая задача стоит и т.д. Как можно обсуждать оптимизацию алгоритма, который решает неизвестно что? К сожалению, я не понимаю по-украински. Переведите задачу, вставьте текст в сам вопрос, здесь по правилам материалы должны быть в самом вопросе, а не где-то по ссылке, которая со временем может стать битой.

Comment: @aepot Добавил перевод задачи

Comment: С этого и надо было начинать, посмотрю позже или кто-то еще здесь посмотрит

Comment: Вам нужен другой алгоритм. Сложность того что вы предложили может достигать *nm*. А можно получить *mlogm + n*.

Comment: Посмотрите перегрузки `int.Parse` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse если при тестировании применяется .NET Core и выше, то можно использовать ReadOnlySpan и парсить строчку не создавая массив, тем самым избавиться от лишних аллокаций и расхода времени на них. А так да, верно говорят. У вас решение в лоб, здесь можно подумать об оптимизациях. Что-то типа обратной трассировки по индексам, стек, быть может, хотя стек на 100000x3 элементов может быть тоже не очень решение.

Comment: А еще в конце создается гигантская строка. Кстати, `string.Join` принимает на вход `char` как разделитель, не только `string`, это может тоже ускорить процесс.

Comment: Пока в голове такое: собираем все запросы (*m*), создаём сортированную очередь концов запросов (*m log(m)*), делаем заметание. В статусе - куча из индексов запросов красящих данный отрезок. Из кучи извлекается максимум (*log(m)*) - он и красит. На событии куча обновляется за *log(m)* - добавляется или убирается один элемент. Покраска за *n*. В сумма *m log(m) + n*. Вместо кучи подойдет `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: @aepot, ограничения по *10^5*. Там нет больших данных. Ввод/ввод на таких объёмах - миллисекунды. А тормозят перекрывающиеся операции рисования.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy здесь на чистой техничке можно x2 сделать, если дотнет не древний, просто свести количество аллокаций к минмуму. А так да, обратная трассировка должна помочь. Красить с конца, пропуская покрашеное и как только пустых ячеек не останется, дропнуть остатки и выдать результат.

Comment: а какой скорости может идти речь, если каждую итерацию запрашивается ввод с консоли..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если *n = m = 10<sup>5</sup>* и все запросы красят все ячейки, программа работает около десяти секунд. Если закомментировать вызов `Array.Fill`, программа работает быстрее 0.2c. Ускоряя ввод/вывод мы можем выиграть 0.2с. Этого недостаточно чтобы уложиться в ограничения по времени. Надо ускорять алгоритм.

Текущий алгоритм работает за *O(mn)* в худшем случае.

Задачу можно решить быстрее заметанием по номеру ячейки. Каждый запрос на рисование превращается в два события - начало и конец отрезка, который закрашивается. Все события сортируются по позициям. По событиям проводится заметание. В статусе все запросы, которые красят текущую позицию. Позиция окрашивается в цвет запроса у которого максимальный номер (в цвет последнего запроса). При обработке события статус обновляется за *O(log(m))*. За тоже время из статуса извлекается последний запрос. Статус хранится в `SortedSet`.

Общая сложность по времени *O(m·log(m) + n)*, по памяти *O(m)*.

Пример для следующего входа:

> ```
> 7 4
> 1 4 7
> 6 6 1
> 4 6 2
> 5 7 1
> ```

События:

> ```
>    Запрос    начальное событие    конечное событие
> i  l r c     (l, true, i, c)      (r+1, false, i, c)
>
> 0  1 4 7     (1, true, 0, 7)      (5  , false, 0, 7)
> 1  6 6 1     (6, true, 1, 1)      (7  , false, 1, 1) 
> 2  4 6 2     (4, true, 2, 2)      (7  , false, 2, 2)
> 3  5 7 1     (5, true, 3, 1)      (8  , false, 3, 1)
> ```

События упорядочиваются по первому значению. Если событие соответствует началу отрезка, в статус добавляется пара из номера запроса и цвета. Событие конца удаляет соответствующую пару.

Все ячейки между двумя соседними событиями окрашиваются в цвет последнего по времени запроса в статусе. Статус упорядочен по номерам запросов, цвет берётся из самого правого элемента - последнего по времени запроса:

> ```
> Событие             Статус                      Окраска
> (p, start, i, c)    {(i, c), ...}               c -> [l, r)
>
>                     {}                          -
> (1, true , 0, 7)
>                     {(0, 7)}                    7 -> [1, 4)
> (4, true , 2, 2)
>                     {(0, 7), (2, 2)}            2 -> [4, 5)
> (5, false, 0, 7)
>                     {(2, 2)}                    2 -> [5, 5)
> (5, true , 3, 1)
>                     {(2, 2), (3, 1)}            1 -> [5, 6)
> (6, true , 1, 1)
>                     {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)}    1 -> [6, 7)
> (7, false, 1, 1) 
>                     {(2, 2), (3, 1)}            1 -> [7, 7)
> (7, false, 2, 2)
>                     {(3, 1)}                    1 -> [7, 8)
> (8, false, 3, 1)
>                     {}                          -
> ```

Помимо описанного в примере, программа до начала заметания добавляет событие на правом конце картины и нулевой цвет в статус. Это нужно чтобы те места картины где нет запросов (то есть статус пуст) были закрашены нулевым цветом.

В худшем случае новая версия работает быстрее чем за 0.6c.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Pair = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, int>;

public class Temp {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        string[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int n = Int32.Parse(line[0]); 
        int m = Int32.Parse(line[1]); 
        
        // position, start?, request, color
        var events = new (int, bool, int, int)[2 * m + 1]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {  
            string[] line2 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int left  = Int32.Parse(line2[0]); 
            int right = Int32.Parse(line2[1]);   
            int color = Int32.Parse(line2[2]);
            events[2 * i    ] = (left     , true , i, color);
            events[2 * i + 1] = (right + 1, false, i, color);
        }
        events[2 * m] = (n + 1, false, -1, 0);

        Array.Sort(events);

        // request, color
        var requests = new SortedSet<Pair>(
            Comparer<Pair>.Create((x, y) => x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key))
        );
        requests.Add(new Pair(-1, 0));

        int prevPosition = 1;
        foreach (var e in events) {
            var (position, start, request, color) = e;
            int cp = requests.Max.Value;
            for (int i = prevPosition; i < position; ++i) {
                Console.Write(cp + " ");
            }
            prevPosition = position;
            var pair = new Pair(request, color);
            if (start) {
                requests.Add(pair);
            } else {
                requests.Remove(pair);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я тронут усилиями, которые Вы потратили. Не знаю, как благодарить. Не будет ли наглости  еще немного спросить? Кор рабочий - выполняетя, я проверял. Но онлайн-компилятор для школьников ругается на строку 
foreach (var (position, start, request, color) in events) {

Comment: /algotester/src/main.cs(34,9): error CS0230: Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement
/algotester/src/main.cs(34,55): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `in'
/algotester/src/main.cs(34,64): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)'

Comment: Можно как-то переделать, чтоб протолкнуть?

Comment: Поправил код. У меня решение приняли.

Comment: Снимаю шляпу! Теперь буду изучать Ваше решение